# How to update Xml contents in a database?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

So there is xml column in a database with some xml file contents. I mean each row of that column holds xml elements like

```
<xml>
<xml1> data </xml1>
</xml
```

What i had to do was read those elements from that column, update their values and update the xml with new values in the database. I can read and calculate the new values but how do I update the contents back to the database.

I use this code to read the elements:

```
DataTable table = ((DataView)gridView2.DataSource).ToTable();

foreach (DataRow dtrow in table.Rows)
{
xdoc.LoadXml(Convert.ToString(dtrow["Contents"]));
}
```

Then i calculate the new values, but how do i update this back to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You have the ability to query the database, you manipulate your xml, but then updating the database is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string")) {
  string sql = "UPDATE table1 Set field1 = '" + xdoc.OuterXml + "'";
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
  con.Open();
  com.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: When you call "Dispose()" on a SqlConnection, internally, it calls "Close()", too. Dispose is called automatically at the end of the using block.

Comment: @MihaiHantea Yes, but this is just a sample code. If there is no `Close()`, then it's confusing for those who don't know, and those who know will not be looking at this answer anyway. Obviously, you should not inject your xml in text sql like this, too. ;)

Comment: Do i have to add some reference? Because my xdoc doesn't have getxml() method.

Comment: Use OuterXml and no need for a reference. I edited my answer.

Comment: @maestrosan11 Did OuterXml work for you? Have you solved you issue?